# Subtract and sum from 2 .txt file at the same time

Tags: haskell

How to get the l by only typing once in order to do the 2 func (subtract and sum) from 2 .txt file at the same time? Is that any higher order function can be use? Kindly appreciate your help.

```
transfer :: IO()
transfer = do

    k <- readFile "balance1.txt"
    b <- readFile "balance2.txt" --------read the second file------
    putStrLn "The amount that need to transfer"
    l <- getLine
    let n = read l::Int
    let a = read k::Int
    let c = read b::Int
    if ( n < a ) 
        then do
        let o = a - n
        let d = show o
            let e = n + c
        putStrLn "Your new balance is"
        putStrLn(d)
        writeFile "balance1.txt" d -----------modify 1st file--------
        writeFile "balance2.txt" e -----------modify 2nd file--------
        else do 
        putStrLn "Amount is not valid"
```

Comment: What does "at the same time" mean? You want some kind of ACID-like guarantees, or what?

Comment: "at the same time" Means I wanted to readFile and WriteFile with 2 txt file in once particular function. Is this a concurrency haskell function? However, is it possible with my code above to do that?

Comment: If you want to give the operations the possibility to execute in parallell you can just chuck a `forkIO` into the mix (and make sure the main thread does not terminate prematurely.) However, you gotta ask yourself *why* you want to do that. You will gain nothing in the program you posted the source to.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`mapM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3amapM):

```hs
transfer = do
    [b1, b2] <- mapM readFile ["balance1.txt", "balance2.txt"]
    -- ...
```

Note that this just reads the two text files in order; you probably don't want concurrency here, anyway.